# How can I make my genealogy tree responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am building a family website, as part of the website, on of the features is the family genealogy tree which shows the family history

The code works well but the only problem is that the genealogy tree is not responsive, it breaks on small screens or if the tree is large like if its a children in any line, the tree breaks instead of showing in a straight line.

It is not responsive.

Here is the code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto
}

.tree>ul>li>a,
.tree li li li a,
.tree>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  width: auto;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
    any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
    right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                                    </a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                                    </a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" style="color:#D520BE"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I make it responsive and such that it does not break?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue? Or did you find a different solution?

Comment: No, it didn't, am still searching for solution to it, am managing it for now till I find a good solution to it

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how could it be really responsive, since the tree needs a minimum width to fit without breaking. I think the next best option is to let the tree be as wide as it wants and make it scrollable in the viewport.

I did that by appending this to your CSS:

```
.tree ul {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Disclaimer:

`max-content` is a relatively recent feature, so old browsers (like IE) don't support it, and some browsers need vendor prefixes. See the [caniuse page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) for details.